# What's this large tree with wrinkled brown fruit in Somaliland?

Tags: identification, trees

Can you please tell what type is this tree? It's large and has brown fruit which you can see in the photos.

It's located in Hargesia, the capital of [Somaliland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somaliland), on a coastal area in the region of Africa. It's about 1370m above sea level.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi amaj. Is this fruit how it naturally grows, or has it gone by? There are some interesting fruit trees in your area, so I want to make sure this is the fruit in its regular state to try to help us identify it.

Comment: @amaj I've spent some time looking for this tree and getting frustrated.  Could you tell me how large these little pods are that look sort of date like?  And these then flatten to the pod on the upper left?  Closer look at the foliage would help and do you remember the flowers?  Color, type?  A picture with something to show scale such as a dime? Or ruler?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Neem Tree](https://neemtreefarms.com/adadirachta-indica-vs-melia-azedarach/), (Azadirachta indica or Melia azedarach). There are other posts about this tree on this site. Search "Melia" or "Neem".

[image]
[image]